How can I solve the "Fetching..." issue when assigning users or groups permissions to folders or apps?
In Sequoia 15.1 (but looks an old known issue). Using the GUI, I created a group to bind it to a folder and an application. On both, this happens:

I searched the web but some solutions look very risky as they issue long command line strings in a recursive manner applied to the filesystem (e.g. Apple post on issue).
If solution using this way is far from complicated, how would you, using command line (chown, chmod,chgrp?):

Bind (append) a group to a folder or app without overwriting current users/groups.
Touch/change just the group/user permissions on that folder or app (leaving alone other users/groups on same app/folder).


What precisely is the issue? If you close the dialog and reopen, aren’t the permissions all fixed as soon as you modify or are you unable to use it to make changes? Also do you need posix groups or ACL groups? The syntax is different for each and each has limitations and advantages.

@bmike Weirdly: you create a group in System Settings. Normally. Then you right click on the folder or app to get to the menu and press + to add that group you already created. Then that happens. It stays forever with the spinning thing. Even if you close it and right click again to see the permissions for that app/folder the spining thing persists. This was in the context of an app that was silently crashing because it was attempting to save a file in a folder (inside Documents\AppFolder. Nothing exotic) and operating system was refusing.

I workaround the issue just erasing the Documents\AppFolder, uninstalling the app. And the app on reinstall created a fresh new folder and everything was solved.

@bmike I am interested in what you are mentioning: "posix groups" and "ACL groups". Where can I study more on that? Do they conflict? Do they overlap? Do they live in harmony? How do I get that information with a regular ls listing? How they cohabitate in my Mac?

Here’s a start for ACL on macOS command line. POSIX permissions are the owner, group, everyone triad familiar to unix.

The screenshot shows that you're trying to modify an object owned by root, but the closed padlock icon shows that you're not acting with root privileges. You have to click that icon and authenticate. The padlock will then show as open, and you should be able to do what you want.

Linc, I made it with padlock open, closed, etc. In every manner. Nothing worked. By the way, is strange that if that was just the case, there was not a trivial error message of some kind informing you have not permissions for doing whatever. As I said, I did it also with the padlock opened and the "Fetching..." was either.
By the way! Your profile image could be the same that I saw in an Apple post about this suggesting the long command line string for tinkering permissions that I referred above?

Even more: with the padlock closed you cannot even touch + or - to add or remove users/group (see the degraded grey). That "Fetching..." snapshot was after adding the group with full permissions (I am superuser) and coming back minutes later, the padlock went on automatically after closing the windows, doing other things and coming back to see if the permission was finally settled ok and I got that snapshot. Sadly, it was not.

What folder are you trying to modify? If it's a built-in application or anything on the read-only System volume, you can't modify it even as root. Also, if you're referring to a post on another site, please link to it.

Searching for the issue, I found interesting things like this: Apple post on Fetching...

(I already happily solved the issue 2 hours ago [not still the question of this post itself, just the original problem], wiping out the controversial folder and reinstalling with my admin privileges which regenerated a sanitized folder). An external 3rd party app, was crashing when trying to use a component from a folder in /Documents that that app itself creates on installation. I got a mad month on this. Finally I solved it. Anyway I am still interested in the good answer of this post. Also the command line way would be gold: "Create folder.. Use ... to bind group to... Use chown...".

The idea behind all, was creating a group to bridge (equalize) permissions (read, write, execute) between the application and the folder --> "I (superuser), that belongs to the privileged created group, launch the app that is accesible with its entitlements also from that group that at the same time opens a folder also accesible in those terms for the group".

Probably what you were looking for is an ACL. See the chmod(1) man page for an explanation. That post on Apple Discussions is 10 years old and obsolete.
